# Dynamic memory allocation and pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, sizeof

I'm trying to understand the difference between these two snippets. Both of them work fine.

```
int rows = 4;

int **p = malloc(rows * sizeof(int **)); //it works without type casting
```

and

```
int**p = (int **) malloc(rows * sizeof(int*)); // using casting method.
```

What does `sizeof(int**)` mean?

Comment: Malloc returns a void * which can be converted to any other type without explicit casting. In C that is. The argument for not casting at all (as in the first line you entered) runs back to what happens if you forget to include stdlib.h on certain compilers. The default is to assume malloc returns an int so if you cast you are saying this is fine.

Comment: One could possibly argue that sizeof(int *) is probably the same as sizeof(int **) and you are getting away with it, but the first line is still wrong and the second line, in C (not C++) doesn't need (and probably should not have) the case to (int **).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allocate an array of `foo_t`s, the standard pattern is one of these:

```
foo_t *p = malloc(count * sizeof(foo_t));
foo_t *p = malloc(count * sizeof(*p));
```

You either say "give me *count* items of size *s*", where the size is either `sizeof(foo_t)` or `sizeof(*p)`. They're equivalent, but the second is better since it avoids writing `foo_t` twice. (That way, if you change `foo *p` to `bar *p` you don't have remember to change `sizeof(foo_t)` to `sizeof(bar_t)`.)

So, to allocate an array of `int *`, replace `foo_t` with `int *`, yielding:

```
int **p = malloc(count * sizeof(int *));
int **p = malloc(count * sizeof(*p));
```

Notice that the correct size is `sizeof(int *)`, not `sizeof(int **)`. Two stars is too many. The first snippet where you wrote `sizeof(int **)` is, therefore, wrong. It appears to work, but that's just luck.

Notice also that I did not include an `(int **)` cast. The cast will work, but [it's a bad idea to cast the return value of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). The cast is unnecessary and could hide a subtle error<sup>*</sup>. See the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) for a full explanation.

---

<sup>* Namely, forgetting to `#include <stdlib.h>`.</sup>

Comment: The famous C-faq also has the answer to this (http://c-faq.com/malloc/cast.html) along with many other answers to confusing C minutiae.